# Bootstrap Navbar Customization - transparent except a new line/bar

Tags: html, css, navbar

I am customizing the Bootstrap navbar to be transparent and was able to force this using the !important tag on my css...

```css
.navbar-default {
  background-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar transparent navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
      <a href="contact.html" class="navbar-brand">Meredith Bristol</a>
    </div>

    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="personal.html">About Meredith</a></li>
        <li><a href="resumewebsite.html">Employment History</a></li>
        <li><a href="education.html">Education</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

However, I am now seeing a horizontal line/bar below the navbar itself, [click here to see example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hn1Vh.png) What is creating this line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a `border-bottom` added by bootstrap, so you need to make its color transparent also (or remove it) :

```css
/* only to show there is no more border/background on the navbar */
body {
  background-color: lightblue!important;
}
/**/

.navbar-default {
  background-color: transparent !important;
  border-color: transparent !important;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<nav class="navbar transparent navbar-default navbar-static-top">
  <div class="container">

    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" data-target="#navbarCollapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="navbar-toggle">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
      <a href="contact.html" class="navbar-brand">Meredith Bristol</a>
    </div>

    <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="contact.html">Contact Me</a></li>
        <li><a href="personal.html">About Meredith</a></li>
        <li><a href="resumewebsite.html">Employment History</a></li>
        <li><a href="education.html">Education</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```